# How to use Input statement in sql query in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am really struggling here .. so immediate help would be appreciated. Have to submit a project tomorrow. If this question is repeated please do send me the link for the answer.

**THE CODING:**

```
if user_input==4:
    station_name_p=input("name of station you want details of?")
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="railways")
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    mycursor("select * from station where Station_name=station_name_p")
    for n in mycursor:
            print(n)
```

What is the error here? Python is not showing an error nor is it showing an output.

I have a table station with column Station_name in railways database

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
if user_input==4:
    station_name_p=input("name of station you want details of?")
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="railways")
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(f"select * from station where Station_name={station_name_p}")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for n in myresult:
        print(n)
```

But **be careful** you should never directly insert user input into a Query. You should always escape and validate input. Research about *Query prepare* and *SQL injection*.